# InnoSetup SaveStringToFile - Unknown identifier error

Tags: inno-setup

In the define section:

```
#define DefaultLanguage "English"
```

---

In the code section :

```
[Code]
procedure MyPro();
begin
    SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\Language.ini'),  {#DefaultLanguage}, False);
end;
```

-->
I got the error : **Unknown identifier 'English'**. The error standing on the command SaveStringToFile. Note that i don't want to pick "English" directly inside the command. I want to define it as a variable.

How to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Tried `"{#DefaultLanguage}"` ?

Comment: @AlexK., better `'{#DefaultLanguage}'` ;-)